# Meteor.subscribe и Minimongo

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor

```
Meteor.publish('groups', function (mask, strict) {
    strict = strict ? true : false;
    check(mask, Match.Integer);
    check(strict, Boolean);

    return Groups.find({
        $where: function () {
            console.log(mask, strict)
            return (strict ? this.state & mask != 0 : this.state & mask == mask)
        }
    });
});
```

Не могу понять почему при

```
Meteor.subscribe('groups', 1, false);
```

Возвращаются все документы. В туториалах которые я встречал подобное прокатывает.

А судя по выводу в консоль $where вообще вызывается.

Благодаря insecure начал тестить в клиентской консоли. Выяснил, что $where вызывается только в .fetch() и в .forEach(...).

Тогда возникает вопрос чем пользуется {{#each}} если он не вызывает ни одну из перечисленных функций?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Так и не понял почему, но в publish работает только текстовый вариант 
$where

```
Meteor.publish('groups', function (mask, notStrict) {
    notStrict = notStrict !== false;
    check(mask, Match.Integer);
    check(notStrict, Boolean);

    return Groups.find({
        $where: '(' + notStrict + ' ? (this.state & ' + mask + ') != 0 : (this.state & ' + mask + ') == ' + mask + ')'
    });
});
```